# D3 Treemap - implement a sort to show all data as horizontal lines

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, treemap

I've just started using D3 to create TreeMaps and I was wondering if anyone knows how I could create a treemap that positions all the elements as fixed width horizontal rectangles (I believe it would require some amendment to the sort function) so that all data is stacked on top of each other like a one column table, with the heights varying based on the data?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: So what you want is a horizontal bar chart?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no, I believe it's more like a horizontal histogram, but I am hoping to build functionality like the D3 treemap example as it will be area based e.g.100% would be the whole canvas, and let's say 20% are for apples, 40% for pears and 40% for oranges, with drill downs to similar 'stacked percentage' canvases.I would expect horizontal lines of equal width and relative area. Are you suggesting that I should use a different graph i.e. am I over engineering here!

Comment: Yes, I think you're overcomplicating this. That's exactly what a bar chart does -- the size of the bars is proportional to the value they represent.

Comment: Thanks Lars - I haven't come across a D3 bar chart example that has interactivity such as the functionality present in this treemap: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ I had presumed I needed to build my graph similar to this to gain this functionality but perhaps I need to look into the bar chart implementation more. I'd be very grateful of any similar examples you could point me to if you know any. Thanks again, John

Comment: Ok, if you want the same kind of interactivity as in the treemap, it may be best to use a treemap.

Comment: Excellent - now I just need someone who knows how to get the data to stack in one column! Thanks for the response anyway. ;)

Comment: Try `.mode("slice")`.